# Exclude result from mysql_fetch_row()

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have the following code which lists all the tables in a database, what I want to do is exclude a table name from the list.

```
$listtables = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
if($listtables){
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($listtables)) {
    echo "{$row[0]}<br>";
 }
}
```

Which Outputs Say :

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now what should I do to exclude 3 from the list? Thanks for any help.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: `if ($row[0] == 3) continue;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am working on that as well but for now I am looking for a solution to this problem. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a SQL where clause for this purpose.

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE tables_in_db_name <> '3';
```

If you need to exclude multiple:

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE tables_in_db_name NOT IN ('3', '5');
```

Replace `db_name` with your database name.

Comment: All the answers work, but actually I was looking for something which excludes multiple results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$listtables = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES WHERE `Tables_in_[database_name]`!='3'");
if($listtables){
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($listtables)) {
    echo "{$row[0]}<br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Also just a pet-peave, `echo $row[0] . '<br />';`

Comment: IMHO `echo "{$row[0]}<br>"` this is very ugly to read as a developer, `echo $row[0] . '<br />';` is much nicer.  but its not a problem.. just my opinion :P